# How to check whether a cookie exists or not?

Tags: nginx

How to check whether a cookie exists or not?  I tried several way but in vain.

```
if ($cookie__id = "-" ){
    return 302 http:/cookie_sync_server/sync
}
empty_gif
```

I would like to do cookie sync if there is no cookie exist.

I tried
    $cookie__id = "-"
    $cookie__id = 0
    $cookie__id = false
    $cookie__id = ""
, all of them are not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
if ($cookie__id){
```

Be careful if you use "if" in location context. More information:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/